# Three asp.net question

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

All my questions in this topic related to asp.net 2.0

While working on some old project when i first opened it Visual studio asked me if i want to convert project from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net 3.5. Is it safe to chose yes ?

If i chosen no in the previous question, how can i later still convert it to asp.net 3.5 ? (Visual studio gave this option in the first  place, so i guess it is possible to do later)

And the last question. Is is possible to bind GridView to the List object ?

Thanks a lot for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to switch to a 3.5 site as long as you are going to deploy to a server that has 3.5.

2.0 sites can always be changed to 3.5 sites.  You can remove the .suo file and reopen the solution, and I believe you will be reasked the question.  Otherwise, right-click on the project in the solution explorer and pull up its properties page, then where it says target framework just change it to "Framework 3.5".

As for a Gridivew, you can bind to a List.

Soming like:

```
List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
Populate(customers);
GridView1.DataSource = customers;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes - but there may be minor changes required (usually outside the .NET framework. ex: crystal reports, etc.)
2. Yes - Project Properties >> Application >> Target Framework.
3. What?  From Gridview to List?  Either way - Yes - New List(GridView1.Items) -or- GridView1.DataSource = List;

Answer (score 1):

If you have any third party components (active reports, infragistics, telerik) you need to be assured that changing .NET versions will not break or affect their behavior.  That is the biggest thing I would watch out for.

Comment: The projects has mix of asp.net ajax starting from version 1.0 and 2.0 and some heavy flash and probably more. 
But overall it is small project, maybe 9-11 web pages